# How to center align script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple game using  Then in the code for the JavaScript I made a canvas.
I'd like this to be centered align/positioned somewhere on the page, though I can not figure out how to do so. Here is the game:

[Game](http://shanebacon.com/simplecanvasgame/)

```
<body>
    <div>
        <script src='js/game.js'></script>
        <div class='about'>

            <h2>Controls:</h2>
            <p>Use the <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> and <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span> arrows to control the bacon eater.</p>
            <h2>Rules:</h2>
            <p>Collect the highest amount of bacon in the alloted time amount
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

centering elements is fairly easy to do with CSS.  Enclose the elements in a `div` and apply the following html rules:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: *some-percent-here*%;
```

Hope this helps!
Cheers.

Edit:

for example, if you wanted to center the `about` section with a width of 50%, you would use:
(background color for visualization purposes...)

```
.about {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 50%;

   background-color: blue;
}
```

Note: This will center the div - not the content inside the div.

For text centering use:

```
text-align: center;
```

---

For completeness, it should be noted that it is *possible* to center the div using styles applied by javascript.  However, it seems to me that your solution wants static placement of the canvas - making html the better choice...

Comment: I tried to add a div but the script seems to be put at the bottom of the page ignoring anything else around it, including divs. Anything else that might work?

Comment: The script doesn't determine the location of the game. Try including your canvas in the `div`.

Comment: See here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp ... In other words, try creating your canvas in the html rather than the javascript. (I believe this is your problem)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your CSS rules for the body selector to be as follows:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}
```